# RewriteRule that overrides another RewriteRule or at least be more specific

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, multilingual

I build a website with multiple languages, and until now I did a simple rewrite for internal pages.

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]`

So all my pages are like this:

```
    website.com/about
```

But now I added another rule, for multiple languages

`RewriteRule ^/?(en|es|ar|fr|de|ru|pt-br)/(.+?)/?$ /$2&lang=$1 [L]`

The problem is, I have more pages, like the index page or profile pages, like this:

```
website.com/en/
website.com/en/profile.php
```

both of them are not working anymore because they redirect me to different pages. like

```
page.php?id=en
page.php?id=profile.php&lang=en
```

I'm pretty confused on what is the solution for this.

Note that I don't want my main language to have a prefix /he/

This is the entire htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /error

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(en|es|ar|fr|de|ru|pt-br)/(.+?)/?$ /$2&lang=$1 [L]
```

I want these

```
website.com/
website.com/en/
website.com/en/profile.php
website.com/about
website.com/en/about
```

to match these

```
website.com/
website.com/?lang=en
website.com/profile.php?lang=en
website.com/page.php?id=about
website.com/page.php?id=about&lang
```

Comment: Change the _order_ of the rules in your .htaccess, and see what you get then.

Comment: Please include your complete `.htaccess` file. And examples of requested URLs and the expected result. The directives you've posted won't result in the output as stated. For a start, a request for `/en/` is not matched by either rule. And a request for `/en/profile.php` would end up being rewritten to `/page.php?id=profile.php&lang=en` (not `page.php?id=profile.php?lang=en` as you've stated). The issue here being that the first rule will rewrite the already rewritten URL by the second rule. Simply changing the order of the rules will not help in this instance.

Comment: I added this information at the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it works:

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /error

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(en|es|ar|fr|de|ru|pt-br)/?$ ?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(en|es|ar|fr|de|ru|pt-br)/(.*).php /$2.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(en|es|ar|fr|de|ru|pt-br)/?(.*) /page.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I tested it with [this website](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/)